# Why my PC can't run NFS Most Wanted 2012 smoothly?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

I have Acer Aspire r11 4 GB RAM model. I don't know why my laptop can't run NFS Most Wanted 2012 smoothly even on lowest graphics settings. It requires 2.4 GHz core 2 duo and 2 GB of system RAM, while my laptop's processor have 4 cores that goes upto 2.4 GHz and 4 GB of RAM. So what is the problem with my laptop?

Please help.

Comment: [Your laptop](http://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/models/laptops/aspirer11) doesn't meet the [minimum required graphics card](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/requirements/need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012/11368) for the game

Comment: @PrivatePansy please, make that an answer.

Comment: Possibly off topic and would be better suited for technical issues, idk lowl:P

Answer (score 4):

Like many low-end laptops, the Acer Aspire r11 doesn't boast a graphics card designed for gaming. It won't be able to run games that aren't either extremely old or use more than very simple graphics.

Laptops in general are not built for gaming. Compared to desktops, laptops have less internal space under the hood, meaning larger and more powerful items cannot be placed there. This also reduces the heat management capabilities greatly that desktops often offer.

Unfortunately, unless you splurge and purchase a gaming-specific laptop or desktop, you will have problems running even games like [Minecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft) at 60 frames per second on the lowest settings.

Comment: I was in two minds whether or not to approve that suggested edit, so if you're not happy with it feel free to roll it back